# How to select Face Set or Mask in Edit Mode?

Tags: edit-mode, selection-tools, sculpt-mode

We can create Face Sets from edit mode's selection. But what I'd like to do is the opposite: I already have Face Sets in sculpt mode, and I'd like to select them in edit mode.

Is it possible?

Comment: Face sets is for sculpting mode only

Comment: You can use face maps as shown here https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=PMINZ7JJOAE You can assign multiple face sets to the same face map, unfortunately, it looks like you have to do it one face set at a time.